# Directory path problem on 4.7.30 upgrade

Tags: joomla, upgrade, 4.7

On upgrade to 4.7.30 (Joomla) the status message tells me of path problems. For example, that the directories are not writeable or do not exist. When I try to check/set the directories I get RuntimeException: "Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path"" (full backtrace below), so I cannot access the form to reset directory paths.

Also, there is an error about missing extensions.

This has also seems to affect the Events Listing module in the Joomla front end which gives the message 'Warning Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module.'

Seems to be same or similar to the [problem](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9256/cms-root-path-error-after-upgrade-to-4-7-joomla) fixed in 4.7.6

Any advice please?

**RuntimeException: "Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path""**

```
#0 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(476): Civi\Core\Paths->getVariable("cms.root", "path") #1 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/function.crmResPath.php(55): CRM_Core_Resources->getPath("cms.root", NULL) #2 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%E8/E8B/E8BB6A67%%Path.hlp.php(11): smarty_function_crmResPath((Array:1), Object(CRM_Core_Smarty)) #3 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1270): include("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%E8/E8B/E8...") #4 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(194): Smarty->fetch("CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Path.hlp", NULL, NULL, FALSE) #5 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty/plugins/function.help.php(64): CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch("CRM/Admin/Form/Setting/Path.hlp") #6 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0F/0FF/0FF13161%%Path.tpl.php(9): smarty_function_help((Array:1), Object(CRM_Core_Smarty)) #7 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1911): include("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0F/0FF/0F...") #8 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0CBEC124%%default.tpl.php(19): Smarty->_smarty_include((Array:2)) #9 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1911): include("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%0C/0CB/0C...") #10 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%EA/EAA/EAA96A89%%joomla.tpl.php(84): Smarty->_smarty_include((Array:2)) #11 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(1270): include("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/media/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%EA/EAA/EA...") #12 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Smarty.php(194): Smarty->fetch("CRM/common/joomla.tpl", NULL, NULL, FALSE) #13 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(133): CRM_Core_Smarty->fetch("CRM/common/joomla.tpl") #14 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(99): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->renderForm(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path)) #15 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path), "display") #16 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path), "display") #17 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display") #18 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run() #19 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(283): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_Setting_Path", "Directories", NULL) #20 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15)) #21 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4)) #22 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4)) #23 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke() #24 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(382): require_once("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicr...") #25 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(357): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicr...") #26 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm") #27 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch() #28 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(303): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute() #29 /var/www/clients/client3/web4/web/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute() #30 {main}
```

@import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. Cannot resolve path using "cms.root.path"

[Return to home page.](https://www.fabians.org.nz/administrator/)

function toggle( element ) { var parent = element.parentNode; var className = parent.className; if ( className == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } else { parent.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block'; } }

Comment: I worked my way around most of this this by setting the overrides for all directories in civicrm.settings.php. I can now access the 'Settings - Upload Directories' form again. I still have the ''Warning Error loading module file (). Please restore the file or disable the module." error in the front end at the top of the civievent registration page.

Answer (score 0):

this is a known issue in the Joomla sites, I've seen it all the way up to civi 5.11.0 and i only change one path which is in Resource URL's - CiviCRM Resource URL

Comment: And how would one do that when you can't access that settings dialogue?

Comment: By modifying civicrm.settings.php